# Integration of automated testing in hudson using selenium framework

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm new to web development and web testing. And I want to use Hudson in my continous integration and for my automated testing using selenium. How can I integrate the selenium in hudson, so that everytime I build using hudson, it will automatically execute the automated testing in selenium? What application should I install? By the way I'm using ubuntu as my OS.

I'm building my webapp using asp.net and C#.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would invoke the tests like you would for your normal unit tests. Assuming that you are creating your tests to be run with NUnit then you will need to make sure that that is installed.

Setting up your Selenium project, like a normal class library project, that builds a dll that can run your tests should suffice.

Comment: How can I run that dll from hudson?

Comment: How are you running the dll now in your local machine?

Comment: to make the question easier to understand, how do you run the Selenium test without Hudson?

Answer (score 0):

You can Integrate your Selenium-TestNG/Nunit Framework with Maven, Maven build path you can give in Jenkins/Hudson.